# Problem with accessing element using Pandas UDF in Image Processing

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I was stuck at this for very long time. Not a very familiar user of using Spark for image processing. I was trying to resize images that are loaded into a Spark DF. However, it keeps throwing error that I am not able to access the element in my UDF. I have tried accessing in both UDF and pandas UDF, but it keeps throwing the same error.

```
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, pandas_udf, col

dataset = spark.read.format("image").load("/databricks-datasets/flower_photos/roses")
modified_dataset = roses.select("image.*").select("origin", "data", struct("width", "height").alias("image_dim"))

def resize_image(data, input_dim):
  input_width = input_dim.width
  input_height = input_dim.height
  output_width = input_width * 0.5
  output_height = input_height * 0.5
  img = Image.frombytes("RGB", [input_width, input_height], bytes(data))
  img = resizeimage.resize_cover(img, [output_width, output_height])
  img = np.asarray(img)
  img = bytearray(img)
  return img

@pandas_udf("binary")
def resize_image_udf(img_data, input_dim):
  return pd.Series([resize_image(i, j) for i,j in zip(img_data, input_dim)])

modified_dataset = modified_dataset.withColumn("thumbnail", resize_image_udf(col("data"), col("image_dim")))
modified_dataset.collect()
```

The errors are as below.

```
PythonException: An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'width'', from , line 9. Full traceback below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 21, in resize_image_udf
  File "", line 21, in 
  File "", line 9, in resize_image
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'width'
```

Does anyone have any idea where I have gone wrong? Advice is more appreciated!

I tried accessing the elements from both UDF and Pandas UDF but failed. The same error persists.

Comment: input_width = input_dim.width, here input_dim seems to be a str data type, and thus you get the error

Comment: Thanks Ajeet! I don't think they are string. These 2 fields , width and height, comes from the struct column I have created in line 6. If you run the codes in Databricks, you will see that it is a struct column of 2 integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to the answer above, when inside the Pandas UDF, accessing values from the Nested StructType doesn't look straightforward. The Nested StructType ends up as a dictionaries within a `pd.Series`. This needs quite a bit of unpacking that could be removed if we don't use Nested Structs in the first place. See a simplified code example below:

```
single_img = modified_dataset.select("data").collect()[0]
single_img_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [[1, single_img["data"], (500,500)]],
    "id int, data binary, image_dim struct<width:int,height:int>")

schema = StructType([
    StructField("output_width", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("output_height", IntegerType(), True)
])

def resize_image(img_data, input_width, input_height):
    output_width = input_width * 0.5
    output_height = input_height * 0.5
    return pd.DataFrame({"output_width": output_width, "output_height": output_height}, index=[0])
  
# try to get input and output from img_data
def resize_image_udf2(img_data: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    input_width = [w.get("width") for w in img_data["image_dim"]][0]
    input_height = [h.get("width") for h in img_data["image_dim"]][0]
    return resize_image(img_data, input_width, input_height)
                          
df = single_img_df.groupby("id").applyInPandas(resize_image_udf2, schema)
df.show()
```

| output_width | output_height |
| --- | --- |
| 250 | 250 |

Comment: Thanks so much! Seems like nested columns is not the way to go. It is alright then. I will keep it unnested! Thanks for your awesome help!

Comment: Great! If you would like to mark this question as answered, then others can reference this in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in your code. You forgot to reference the column. You can just use strings in a select, but you can't mix strings and structs.

```
modified_dataset = roses.select("image.*").select(col("origin"), col("data"), struct(col("width"), col("height")).alias("image_dim"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. Nonetheless, I do see merit in referencing the column. It is a good practice. Thanks so much Matt!

Answer (score 0):

It seems much easier to handle your inputs as a Pandas DataFrame using the [Pandas Function APIs](https://docs.databricks.com/pandas/pandas-function-apis.html) instead of passing in your image binary data (`img_data`) and input dimensions (`input_dim`) separately, only to then join them back together with the `zip()` command.

This example seems to work:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, FloatType, ArrayType, BinaryType
from typing import Iterator
from resizeimage import resizeimage
import numpy as np

roses = spark.read.format("image").load("/databricks-datasets/flower_photos/roses")

modified_dataset = roses.select("image.*").select("origin", "data", "width", "height")

schema = StructType(modified_dataset.schema.fields + [
    StructField("data_as_resized_array", ArrayType(IntegerType()), True),
])

def resize_image(img_data) -> pd.Series:
    input_width = img_data.width
    input_height = img_data.height
    output_width = input_width * 0.5
    output_height = input_height * 0.5
    img = Image.frombytes(mode="RGB", data=bytes(img_data.data), size=[input_width, input_height])
    img = resizeimage.resize_cover(img, [output_width, output_height])
    img = np.asarray(img)
    img = bytearray(img)
    return img


def resize_image_udf(dataframe_batch_iterator: Iterator[pd.DataFrame]) -> Iterator[pd.DataFrame]:
    for dataframe_batch in dataframe_batch_iterator:
        dataframe_batch["data_as_resized_array"] = dataframe_batch.apply(resize_image, axis=1)
        yield dataframe_batch
        
resized_df = modified_dataset.mapInPandas(resize_image_udf, schema)
resized_df.show()
```

Is there a reason why you want the input dimensions as a `StructCol` instead of reading the `width` and `height` as separate columns?

Comment: Thanks so much Jeanne! I have tried your method but it didn't work still. I got the error "Invalid return type in mapInPandas". Diving into the traceback it would write "TypeError: Nested StructType not supported in conversion to Arrow".

Comment: As for the reason why I used a StructCol instead of separate columns, it is purely out of convenience, because ideally I hope to be able to avoid unpacking the nested columns in the first place. This is not a must, but it would have looked much neater.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add that I don't have `width` and `height` as a Nested StructType. Updated the example code accordingly. With `width` and `height` as separate columns, the example above should work

Comment: Thanks so much Jeanne! If it is unnested it indeed works!!!